# Servlet: "%2B" is converted into space

Tags: java, servlets, get, getparameter

I have very simple problem

I'm forming one GET request as follows, parameters are

```
para1=abc+xyz
```

Notice the '+' sign here. Now when I url encode this I get `para1=abc%2Bxyz`. *Which is okay!*

Now on servlet side, I have code like following

```
String para1 = request.getParameter("para1")
```

Content of `para1` are `abc xyz` (notice the space).

Shouldn't it be `abc+xyz`? I want the value to be as it was sent from the source, not the messed up one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is decoded as space after `url decoding`. If you want to pass `+`, you need to encode it.

Java

```
 String ecodedValue = URLEncoder.encode("abc+xyz", "UTF-8");
 String decodedValue = URLDecoder.decode(ecodedValue, "UTF-8");
```

[Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(str);
```

[Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp)

```
var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURI(uri);
```

or

```
var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

Answer (score 1):

They're equivalent. Both the + sign and space are translated to spaces. If you want to send a literal + sign, you need to encode it.

Answer (score 0):

You should always encode your parameter values while posting it to a URL. 
You just need to encode your parameter value using,

> URLEncoder.encode(paramValue, "UTF-8");